# css3 animation moving left to right then continue moving from outside to left

Tags: html, css

The red box appeared in the middle of its containter when the page first load then moving from left to right and reappear like this image:

[image]

Here's what i did so far but it does not suit the idea above:

```
.box{
    -webkit-animation: left-to-right 10s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: left-to-right 10s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes left-to-right {
    100%{
        left:-1000px
    }
}

@keyframes left-to-right {
    100%{
        left:-1000px
    }
}
```

Page width is 1280px and box width is 1000px.

Comment: Which one you want to continue to move from outside to left? The square or the rectangle ?

Comment: a square is a part of the rectangle which is outside the content. There's only 1 moving object here: the red rectangle

Comment: Did you try your code too see how it works? In your animation posted as example, you have two objects moving: a rectangle from left to right and a square from right to left. With your code posted, your animation won't even move like in your example.

Comment: Take a look in my post and see how is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPEJzm

```
<div id="animated-example" class="animated shake"></div>



.animated { 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s; 
    animation-duration: 5s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
    animation-timing-function: linear; 
    animation-iteration-count:infinite; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes shake { 
    0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);} 
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);} 
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: translateX(50px);} 
} 
@keyframes shake { 
    0%, 100% {transform: translateX(0);} 
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {transform: translateX(-50px);} 
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {transform: translateX(50px);} 
} 
.shake { 
    -webkit-animation-name: shake; 
    animation-name: shake; 
}
.shake {
  background:red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bvjzmke5/3/

I make it complete in 2s and used -50% to move, change that however you want.

```
.box{
    -webkit-animation: right-to-left 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: right-to-left 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes right-to-left {

    100%{
        left:-50%
        }       
}

@keyframes left-to-right {

    100%{
        left:-50%
        }       

}

.square{
    -webkit-animation: left-to-right 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: left-to-right 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes left-to-right {

    100%{
        right:-50%
        }       
}

@keyframes left-to-right {
    100%{
        right:-50%
        }   
}

<div id="container" style="height:100px; width:60%; margin:0 auto">
<div class="box" style="height:100px; width:50%;background:red;position:relative;display:inline-block"></div>
<div class="square" style="height:100px; width:100px; background:red;position:relative;display:inline-block"></div>
</div>
```